# ios How to add an inputAccessoryView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, inputaccessoryview

I am trying to replicate Facebook Messenger App, where there is a `UITextView` attached to the top of the keyboard.

Due to the nature of this app I need my `view` to be attached, instead of manually scrolling up and down a `ScrollView` when the keyboard appears.

This can be achieved by using a `inputAccessoryView`.

I read the docs on it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIResponder/inputAccessoryView).

The documentation is very brief and says:

"This property is typically used to attach an accessory view to the system-supplied keyboard that is presented for UITextField and UITextView objects.

The value of this read-only property is nil. If you want to attach custom controls to a system-supplied input view (such as the system keyboard) or to a custom input view (one you provide in the inputView property), redeclare this property as read-write in a UIResponder subclass.

You can then use this property to manage a custom accessory view. When the receiver becomes the first responder, the responder infrastructure attaches the accessory view to the appropriate input view before displaying it."

I have tried declaring a property

```
@interface CommentViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) UIView *inputAccessoryView;
@end
```

And then setting it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 100)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    self.inputAccessoryView = view;

}
```

Then I have tried calling both of these:

1. `[self.tableView becomeFirstResponder];`
2. `[view becomeFirstResponder];`

Nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

*Note - Extra information: I am using a `UITableViewController` that I want to have a `UIView` attached as an `inputAccessoryView`. Once I get the view working then I will add in a `UITextView` and more, but this is mainly an example.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have implemented the similar kind of functionality in my current app. Please send me your email id and I will pass on the sample code which you can tailor as per your requirement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add input accessory to your textField or textView rather than to pure UIView.

```
self.mytextField.inputAccessoryView = view;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `inputAccessoryView` is a property of the `UIResponder` class. It allows you to define a custom input accessory view to display when the receiver becomes the first responder. Usually an instance of `UIToolBar` should be set as the accessory view.

A toolbar sample:

`MYInputAccessoryToolbar.h`

```
typedef void (^MYInputAccessoryToolbarDidDoneTap)(id activeItem);

@interface MYInputAccessoryToolbar : UIToolbar

@property (nonatomic, copy) MYInputAccessoryToolbarDidDoneTap didDoneTapBlock;

+ (instancetype)toolbarWithInputItems:(NSArray *)items;

- (instancetype)initWithInputItems:(NSArray *)items;
- (void)addInputItem:(id)item;
- (void)goToNextItem;
- (void)goToPrevItem;

@end
```

`MYInputAccessoryToolbar.m`

```
@interface MYInputAccessoryToolbar ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIBarButtonItem *nextButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIBarButtonItem *prevButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *inputItems;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger activeItemIndex;
@property (nonatomic) id activeItem;

@end

@implementation MYInputAccessoryToolbar

+ (instancetype)toolbarWithInputItems:(NSArray *)items {
    return [[self alloc] initWithInputItems:items];
}

#pragma mark - Initializations

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _inputItems = [NSMutableArray new];

        _prevButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:101 target:self action:@selector(prevButtonTaped)];
        _nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:102 target:self action:@selector(nextButtonTaped)];
        _doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doneButtonTaped)];
        [_doneButton setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
        fixedSpace.width = 20.0f;

        UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

        NSArray<UIBarButtonItem *> *barButtons = @[_prevButton, fixedSpace, _nextButton, flexSpace, _doneButton];

        [self sizeToFit];

        self.items = barButtons;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(itemDidBeginEditing:)
                                                     name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(itemDidBeginEditing:)
                                                     name:UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification
                                                   object:nil];

    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype) initWithInputItems:(NSArray *)items {
    self = [self init];

    for (id item in items) {
        [self addInputItem:item];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Accessors

- (void)addInputItem:(id)item {
    if ([item respondsToSelector:@selector(setInputAccessoryView:)]) {
        [item setInputAccessoryView:self];
    }

    [_inputItems addObject:item];
}

#pragma mark - Actions

- (void)itemDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)noticifation {
    NSInteger itemIndex = [_inputItems indexOfObject:noticifation.object];
    if (itemIndex != NSNotFound && _activeItem != noticifation.object) {
        _activeItemIndex = itemIndex;
        _activeItem      = noticifation.object;
        [self activeItemChanged];
    }
}

- (void)activeItemChanged {
    _prevButton.enabled = _activeItemIndex != 0;
    _nextButton.enabled = _activeItemIndex != _inputItems.count - 1;
}

- (void)prevButtonTaped {
    [self goToPrevItem];
}

- (void)nextButtonTaped {
    [self goToNextItem];
}

- (void)goToNextItem {
    [_inputItems[_activeItemIndex + 1] becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)goToPrevItem {
    [_inputItems[_activeItemIndex - 1] becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)doneButtonTaped {
    if (_didDoneTapBlock) {
        _didDoneTapBlock(_activeItem);
    }
    [_activeItem resignFirstResponder];
}

#pragma mark - Dealloc

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
}

@end
```

Now assuming that we have a set of text field fields and text views we could use them to initialize an instance of our toolbar.

```
MYInputAccessoryToolbar *accessoryToolbar = [MYInputAccessoryToolbar toolbarWithInputItems:@[_passwordCurrentField, _passwordNewField, _passwordVerifyField]];
```

And then each of these fields will have a custom accessory view like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIFwu.png).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `self.inputAccessoryView = view;` and then add the code below anywhere after `-(void)viewDidLoad { ... }` where `view` is your UIView:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    ....
}

- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView
{
   return self.view;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I am posting this answer to show other people my exact code and how easy it actually was, however all the credit goes to MadNik.

In your view controller class where you want a keyboard, in the implementation add the following:

```
@implementation CommentViewController {
    UIView *toolbar;
    UITextView *commentTextView;
    UIButton *postComment;
}
```

The `toolbar` is the actual view that gets docked to your keyboard, and the rest of the objects go on top of the view.

Next it is as simple as initiating the `toolbar` and setting its frame:

```
toolbar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];

[toolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

I make the frame of the toolbar initially sit right at the bottom of the view controller.

Next I just initiate the rest of the objects I want on my toolbar, e.g the `UITextField` and a `UIButton`. Just lay them out how you want:

```
commentTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, self.view.frame.size.width - 16 - 75, 34)];
[commentTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.97 alpha:1]];
commentTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
[commentTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next" size:20]];
[commentTextView setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.35 alpha:1]];

postComment = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-75, 0, 75, 50)];
[postComment setTitle:@"Post" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[postComment.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next" size:20]];
[postComment setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.0) green:(40/255.0) blue:(80/255.0) alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Next add your objects to your tool bar:

```
[toolbar addSubview:commentTextView];
[toolbar addSubview:postComment];
```

Now this is where the magic happens: You simply set your `UITextView`'s inputAccessoryView to **whatever view you want to be docked to the keyboard.**

In this case it is `toolbar`, because the `toolbar` is acting as a dock that holds everything else.

Now all you need to do is add your `toolbar` to your view controller, and when you tap the `UITextView`, since its inputAccessoryView it the `toolbar`, the `toolbar` will be docked to the keyboard!

Since I am using a `UITableViewController`, I had to add my `toolbar` to the window:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate].window addSubview:toolbar];
```

So simple! No extra classes or anything needs to be made!

Comment: Nice story. Very Long. Useless.